# CSS Sprites not working in blogger

Tags: html, css, hover, sprite

i have been trying to get my hover sprite to work in the blogger platform, but only the first image will show up.

my css is as follows:

```
.imagesprite {
    display: block;
    background-image: url(xxx);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.imagesprite:hover {
    width: 400px;
    height: -400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-position: 0, -400px;
}
```

nothing happens then my mouse hovers.

Comment: height shouldn't be negative

Answer (score 1):

Nico is correct. Width and height generally do not change on hover. The only thing you actually need in your :hover statement is the new background-position (which doesn't take a comma). If .imagesprite is a div, you probably don't need display: block or overflow: hidden, either.

```
.imagesprite {
    background-image: url(xxx);
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.imagesprite:hover {
    background-position: 0 -400px;
}
```